# How to select an item which renders a drop-down list of items that match a search

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cypress, headless-ui

I'm attempting to select an item which renders a drop-down list of items that match a search.

I select the correct item once the drop-down list has been opened. The `id` values changes so they cannot be used.

This is the script in Cypress:

```
cy.get('input[placeholder="Search Something"]').type('Your search query').type('{enter}');
cy.contains('div span', 'XXXXX XXX').click();

or 

cy.get('div[role="listbox"]')
  .contains('span', 'XXX XXX')
  .should('exist')
  .click();
```

Below is the inspection from the page:

```
<div 
  class="w-full" 
  id="headlessui-combobox-button-137" 
  tabindex="-1" 
  aria-haspopup="listbox" 
  aria-expanded="true" 
  data-headlessui-state="open" 
  aria-controls="headlessui-combobox-options-139"
>
    <input 
      placeholder="Search Subscribers"  
      class="w-full inputFocus px-4 rounded-3xl text-ever-green  font-beatrice font-normal transition-colors focus:border-cornflower-blue focus:outline-none outline-none placeholder:text-slate-gray h-smButtonHeight text-sm border-2 border-duck-egg-blue"  
      id="headlessui-combobox-input-138"  
      role="combobox"  
      type="text"  
      aria-expanded="true"  
      aria-autocomplete="list"  
      data-headlessui-state="open"  
      value="Prod"  
      aria-controls="headlessui-combobox-options-139"  
      aria-activedescendant="headlessui-combobox-option-156"
    >
</div>
```

Below is the extract from the page the drop down:

```
<div 
  class="absolute z-10 w-full mt-2 overflow-auto text-base bg-white rounded-md shadow-dropdown max-h-60 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm left-0 right-0 mx-auto p-0"  
  aria-labelledby="headlessui-combobox-button-137"  
  role="listbox"  
  aria-multiselectable="true"  
  id="headlessui-combobox-options-139"  
  data-headlessui-state="open"
>
    <div  
      class="relative h-full max-h-60 p-2 overflow-y-auto"   
      role="none"
    >
        <div   
          class="relative"    
          style="height: 32px;"    
          role="none"   
        >   
        <div    
          class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full"     
          id="headlessui-combobox-option-156"     
          role="option"     
          tabindex="-1"     
          aria-selected="true"     
          data-headlessui-state="active selected"     
          style="transform: translateY(0px);"    
        >    
          <span     
            class="cursor-pointer flex items-center gap-x-2 py-1.5 px-4.5 font-medium text-sm transition-colors lg:truncate text-cornflower-blue bg-ice-blue"   
          >   
              <span    
                class="w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 inline-block text-xs">+1 251 230 8828   
              </span>   
              <span    
                class="w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 inline-block text-xs"   
              >   
                  <div class="text-ever-green">Prod 701</div>
              </span>
              <span class="w-1/3 hidden xl:inline-block text-xs"> 
                  <div>
```

Any solutions welcomed.

Comment: To clarify, are you having issues with 1) selecting the item which then renders the drop-down list, or 2) selecting an item once the drop-down list has been opened?

Comment: 2.  selecting an item once the drop-down list has been opened?

Comment: I haven't used this on a span with role=option, but have you tried to use cy.select()?  https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select

Answer (score 4):

This is a `HeadlessUi` component that constructs components from divs, as shown in the code sample.

**Avoiding changing ids**
To access the parts needed for testing, you can use `[role="listbox"]` and `[role="option"]`, which would be the equivalent to `<select>` and `<option>` in plain HTML5.

**Using the correct command sequence**
The relationship between listbox and options is parent-child, so instead of `get().contains()` I recommend `get().find()`.

The way you have done it, the "subject" (the queried element) is the `listbox` instead of the `option`, and click the parent `listbox` doesn't make an `option` selection.

```js
cy.get('[role="listbox"]')
  .find('[role="option"]:contains("XXX XXX")')  // be careful with brackets and quote marks
  .click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which I have adapted from my own for Mantine dropdown boxes. It should be able to be called simply as a function within your test specs.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('selecter', (selectSelector, value) => {
  cy.get(selectSelector).scrollIntoView();
  cy.get(selectSelector).click({ force: true });

  const options = () =>
    cy.get('listbox').find('option');
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    // If the given value is a string, select the option with that label
    return options()
      .contains(value, { matchCase: false })
      .click({ force: true });
  }
  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    // Else if it's a number, select the option at that index
    return options()
      .eq(value)
      .click({ force: true });
  }
  throw new Error(
    `value should be a string or number, but was '${value}' (${typeof value}).`,
  );
});
```